# Electronが起動せず困っています。

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

http://39mamon.com/?p=206
http://qiita.com/Quramy/items/a4be32769366cfe55778
こちらのサイトを参考にElectronの環境を作っていたのですが、うまく動かすことができません。
OSはcentOS6.7です。

cd electron-readus
でフォルダに移動し
sudo npm -g install electron-prebuilt
でインストールを行い必要なファイルを作成

lsで
index.html  main.js  npm-debug.log  package.json
が表示されています。

ここでelectronを入力すると
/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

と表示されます。何かのファイルが足らないのだろうと思うのですが、
ldd electronと入力しても
「ldd: ./electron: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」
とエラーメッセージがでてしまいます。

なにかお気付きの方いらっしゃいましたご連絡ください。

Comment: とりあえずlibgconf-2.so.4の件は解決したようですので、この質問は解決済みにして、GLIBCXX_3.4.15の件はmakeのエラーを添えて新たに別の質問として投稿してください。

Comment: ではそうします〜ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エラーメッセージに表示されているように、electronの実行ファイルの本体は`/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron`にあるので`ldd`にはそのパスを指定してください。

```
$ ldd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron | grep gconf
    libgconf-2.so.4 => not found
```

`yum whatprovides`でそのファイルを提供しているパッケージを検索できます。

```
$ yum whatprovides '*libgconf-2.so.4'

...

GConf2-3.2.6-8.el7.x86_64 : A process-transparent configuration system
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libgconf-2.so.4

...
```

これをインストールします。

```
$ yum install GConf2-3.2.6-8.el7.x86_64
$ ldd /usr/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron | grep gconf
    libgconf-2.so.4 => /lib64/libgconf-2.so.4 (0x00007ffa862ee000)
```

他にも不足しているライブラリがあるかもしれないので、同様の手順でインストールしてください。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。環境整備にだいぶ近ずいた感触です。

教えていただいた通り、足りていないパッケージを入れて行った結果。
[vagrant@localhost dist]$ ldd electron
./electron: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./electron)
./electron: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./electron)...(のこり省略)

と表示され、notFoundは残すところ
GLIBCXX_3.4.15/GLIBC_2.14
の二つになりました。しかし、
yum whatprovides '*GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
を実行しても
「No Matches found」が出てしまっています。

もしまたアドバイスいただけるのでしたら宜しくお願いします。

Comment: @くにしまあつし この記事が参考になりそうです: https://www.saintsouth.net/blog/update-libstdcpp-on-centos6/

Comment: 早速見てみます。ありがとうございます